# Why doesnt my <a href= link work?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'm using a random text editor and saving pages to .html and the "link for gizmodo isn't clickable

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
</head>

<body
<a href="http://www.gizmodo.com">This is the link for gizmodo</a>
</body>

</html>

<!--"a" stands for anchor-->
```

Comment: Use an HTML validator too.  The W3C offered an online validator, and it has the offline HTML Tidy.  However, that's only available as an experimental tool for HTML 5. See https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing bracket of your `<body>` tag. This will cause the HTML for the `<a>` tag to be malformed and not work as expected.:

```
<body  <-- HERE
<a href="http://www.gizmodo.com">This is the link for gizmodo</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The body attribute is `<body> </body>` not `<body </body>`. You are missing a closing `>` on the opening tag.

This is the renovated code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
</head>

<body> <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU FORGOT THE ">" -->
<a href="http://www.gizmodo.com">This is the link for gizmodo</a>
</body>

</html>

<!--"a" stands for anchor-->
```